# Draw ellipse into rectangle in C

Tags: c, bgi

The following C code will draw a rectangle. I know how to draw the ellipse, but how can i draw an ellipse into this rectangle?

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
   int gd = DETECT, gm;

   initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");

   rectangle(100,100,200,200);

   getch();
   closegraph();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want an ellipse that is inscribed in the rectangle (i.e. touches the four sides) or one of the infinite set of ellipses that is contained by the rectangle?

Comment: No eclipse should not touch the sides of rectangle, i need to draw it with a little inset margin :)

Comment: what `graphics` library do you use ?

Comment: graphics.h as my code suggests it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuming you're using the `ellipse` [function](http://www.ousob.com/ng/borcpp/ng78a42.php) from `graphics.h`, you could do the following:

```
 int left = 100;
 int right = 200;
 int top = 100;
 int bottom = 200;

 rectangle(left, top, right, bottom);

 int x = (left + right) / 2;  
 int y = (top + bottom) / 2;  
 int start = 0;
 int end = 360;
 int xrad = (right - left) / 2;
 int yrad = (bottom - top) / 2;

 ellipse(x, y, start, end, xrad, yrad);
```

Comment: So, there's no rocket science :D i only need to reduce its size to display into the rectangle?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the comment until now. Basically, you are inscribing the ellipse into the rectangle, if you need to shrink the ellipse then use shrinked version of `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` for the ellipse and the real version for rectangle